# Laravel 5.2 to 5.3 - converting routes.php to web and api route files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am upgrading my guitar lessons site from 5.2 to 5.3. My previous developer has a full time job so now I am the site owner and developer... I am a better guitarist than developer...

My site has a backend for adding guitar lesson content. The routes.php file, among other things,  had these lines:

```
function RegisterResourceRoute($route, $name) {
    Route::get($route,              'Api\\'.$name.'Controller@getAll');
    Route::get($route.'/{id}',      'Api\\'.$name.'Controller@get');
    Route::post($route,             'Api\\'.$name.'Controller@post');
    Route::put($route.'/{id}',      'Api\\'.$name.'Controller@put');
    Route::delete($route.'/{id}',   'Api\\'.$name.'Controller@delete');
}

// Api
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api', 'auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
        RegisterResourceRoute('file', 'File');
        RegisterResourceRoute('photo', 'Photo');
        RegisterResourceRoute('category', 'Category');
        RegisterResourceRoute('tag', 'Tag');
        RegisterResourceRoute('lesson', 'Lesson');
        RegisterResourceRoute('exercise', 'Exercise');
        RegisterResourceRoute('user', 'User');
    });
    Route::post('/api/email', 'Api\\EmailController@send');

});
```

Then I see in the angular related js used in the view, this for the Exercise resource:

```
// Exercise
        .when('/exercise', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/exercise/view-all.html',
            controller: 'ExerciseViewAllController'
        })
        .when('/exercise/create/:lessonId?', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/exercise/create.html',
            controller: 'ExerciseCreateController'
        })
        .when('/exercise/view/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/exercise/view.html',
            controller: 'ExerciseViewController'
        })
        .when('/exercise/edit/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/exercise/edit.html',
            controller: 'ExerciseEditController'
        })
        .when('/exercise/edit/:id/details', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/exercise/edit-details.html',
            controller: 'ExerciseDetailsController'
        })
        .when('/exercise/edit/:id/photos', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/exercise/edit-photos.html',
            controller: 'ExercisePhotosController'
        })
        .when('/exercise/delete/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/exercise/delete.html',
            controller: 'ExerciseDeleteController'
        })
```

The ViewAllController, for instance, looks like this:

```
angular.module('dashboard')
    .controller('ExerciseViewAllController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.exercises = [];

        $scope.refresh = function () {
            $scope.exercises = [];
            load();
        };

        var load = function () {
            $scope.busy = true;
            $http.get('/api/exercise').then(function (response) {
                $scope.busy = false;
                $scope.exercises = response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                $scope.busy = false;
            });
        };

        load();
    }]);
```

I am trying to figure out how 5.3 handles such routing. In my backend dashboard, when I try and view the list of exercises, for instance, I was getting a 404 error for api/exercise.

So I created web.php with this under admin routes:

```
Route::resource('api/exercise', 'Api\ExerciseController');
```

And in api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () { Route::resource('exercise', 'Api\ExerciseController'); });
```

It now works, but I had to change what was previously a getAll() function in the Exercise controller to index(), otherwise there was a error since laravel was looking for the default index method.

I would rather get it working using default route names, and also I have no idea if what I added to web.php and api.php is really the correct way. I see things seem to work but I am worried I am not seeing the whole picture...

Can someone explain what I would do to get these routes working in the true laravel 5.3 way?

thanks!

Comment: you can contact me using my email: kamgasimojunior@gmail.com am a laravel  developer.

Answer (score 0):

Not remember exactly but I upgraded from 5.2 to 5.3 by this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade
Do not get overwhelmed by the content. just search for bits that you are getting errors from. for example routes section.
Hope that helps